# How to initialize objects based on hierarchy interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have got a interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand is of type ICommand (another interface). 
SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler class implements ICommandHandler.

What i'm unable to do is pass the SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler class to another class where it expects ICommandHandler in its constructor

In the below code Manager class expects ICommandHandler<TCommand> in its constructor. I'm getting compile time error when i pass someWorkProcessCommandHandler object. If i cast it i get run time exception.

How do i pass someWorkProcessCommandHandler object in the constructor?

Please don't tell me to remove it from the constructor and figure out the handler in the Execute method. I'm not trying to do that. The only thing i'm trying to figure here is, how to pass objects that have hierarchy interface

```
    public interface ICommand
    {
    }

    public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        void Handle(TCommand command);
    }

    public class SomeWorkProcessCommand : ICommand
    {
    }

    public class SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SomeWorkProcessCommand>
    {
        public void Handle(SomeWorkProcessCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some work Process Command Handler ");
        }
    }

    public class Manager 
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<ICommand> handler;

        public Manager(ICommandHandler<ICommand> handler)
        {
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public void Execute(ICommand command)
        {

            handler.Handle(command);
        }

    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var someWorkProcessCommandHandler = new SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler();
            someWorkProcessCommandHandler.Handle(new SomeWorkProcessCommand());// This line works fine if the below code is not present

            //var manager = new Manager(someWorkProcessCommandHandler);  //Compile time error
            var manager = new Manager((ICommandHandler<ICommand>)someWorkProcessCommandHandler); //Runtime error after casting
            manager.Execute(new SomeWorkProcessCommand());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your Manager class design. You should use generics there too. Here is the updated code and it would work:

```
public interface ICommand
{
}

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class SomeWorkProcessCommand : ICommand
{
}

public class SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SomeWorkProcessCommand>
{
    public void Handle(SomeWorkProcessCommand command)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some work Process Command Handler ");
    }
}

public class Manager<TCommandHandler, TCommand>
    where TCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly TCommandHandler handler;

    public Manager(TCommandHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        handler.Handle(command);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var someWorkProcessCommandHandler = new SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler();
        someWorkProcessCommandHandler.Handle(new SomeWorkProcessCommand());// This line works fine if the below code is not present

        var manager = new Manager<SomeWorkProcessCommandHandler, SomeWorkProcessCommand>(someWorkProcessCommandHandler);  //Works now
        manager.Execute(new SomeWorkProcessCommand());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to the answer by @tanveery, the `Manager` class really only needs the type constraint on the type parameter that gets passed into `ICommandHandler<>`:

```
public class Manager<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler;

    public Manager(ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

This reduces the use site to:

```
var manager = new Manager<SomeWorkProcessCommand>(someWorkProcessCommandHandler);
manager.Execute(new SomeWorkProcessCommand());
```

Going even further, you could completely remove the need to specify the type parameter at the use site by creating a static factory method, like so:

```
public static class ManagerFactory
{
    public static Manager<TCommand> Create<TCommand>(ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
        where TCommand : ICommand => new Manager<TCommand>(handler);
}
```

The use site would then look like:

```
var manager = ManagerFactory.Create(someWorkProcessCommandHandler);
manager.Execute(new SomeWorkProcessCommand());
```

Comment: I'm getting compilation error at this line. Cannot convert handler to <ICommand>   ```var manager = new Manager<SomeWorkProcessCommand>(someWorkProcessCommandHandler);```